# Wrong measurements obtained in powertop

Tags: powertop

so i was wondering why power gives 0mW for all the processes that are running in my laptop , even thought some of them needs a lot of computation, here's a screenshot of the output of powertop, thank you.[the result obtained in powertop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSqlZ.png)

Comment: "all"? I see 2 with a number not 0 and 1 of them with a staggering 317W. That is 1 heck of a power drain that radio device... and I'd turn that backlight off too if I was you...

Comment: yeah there are two and those are devices , that consumes a lot of power, but all the others are at 0, i don't understand why

Comment: could be callibration. Can you try with these 2 high turned off?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should try an alternative tool, such as powerstat, c.f. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/powerstat/

```
sudo apt-get install powerstat
powerstat
```

Comment: does it give you the possibility to see power usage per process?

Comment: afraid not. just overall system power. If you have Intel RAPL support it does allow one to see the power consumed by the CPU core, package and also GPU.    Generally,  the amount of CPU being used by a process does related to the amount of power being used, so one could use tools like "top" to see the busy CPU consumers.

Comment: that's the problem , i need a tool that gives me power usage for a certain process, i don't care if it's powertop, i just need it to work on linux, if you have any suggestions, i'll be very grateful.

Comment: According to https://lwn.net/Articles/569674/,  perf can read the RAPL stats from modern CPUs (Intel SandyBridge, IvyBridge, Haswell) and perhaps will give you what you need.    This is not trivial and I am not sure how accurate it is.